# What kinds of jobs could a senior in high school get at a small local airport?

Tags: airport

Is there anything a senior in high school could do for a small regional airport in Utah?

Answer (score 7):

Sure! When I was a senior in high school I had a job as a line boy at a local FBO. We refueled aircraft, cleaned aircraft and moved them in and out of hangars. Not the most glamorous job but it was the beginning of the never ending learning process of aviation.

Comment: An FBO at my local airport (sorry OP, not in Utah)  advertised just such a position on FB earlier today. In addition to the usual benefits, they offer a discount on flight training. I wish I had thought of that in HS!